# Java overriding and interfaces

Tags: java, methods, intellij-idea, overriding, superclass

I use intellij IDEA 14.

I've got the following problem. Let the class `ClassA` be implemented from interface `A`, class `ClassB` be implemented from interface `B` and class `ClassC` be implemented from interface `C`.

Interface `A` has method `Object method (B b, C c) {...}` but I can't create an interface object, so I solved to override this method `Object method(...) {...}` in my class `ClassA` like that:

```
...
@Override
Object method (ClassB b, ClassC c) { // But here compiler writes an error "method does not override method from its superclass"
...
}
...
```

But it can't be compiled because of `method does not override method from its superclass`. But why? Why we can use, for example, HashMap which is implemented from Map?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just don't do that.

Imagine if, for example, you have two more classes. `ClassB2 implements B` and `ClassC2 implements C`. Your method wouldn't be applicable to parameters `(ClassB2 b2, ClassC2 c2)` while `Object method (B b, C c)` would be OK with it. And there, you have inconsistency between interface and implementation.